# Sending out batch file email to run a powershell script to update users folder

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file, google-drive-api, mirror

I am wanting to send out a file that others in my company can use to update a local folder from a Google Drive folder.

I have a PowerShell 7 script that works on my local computer:

```
robocopy "C:\Users\(insert username)\AppData\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.13\packages" "G:\Shared drives\(Insert Drive Name)\STANDARDS\DYNAMO\Packages\2.13\packages" /mir
```

I tried making a batch file using `%appdata%` to send out but it would just create a new folder in the folder containing the script. I then read that powershell doesn't use `%appdata%`

I tried using "$env:appdata" to locate the local file but nothing would happen. Can anyone help me with the proper syntax?

Here is the script I was trying:

```
robocopy "G:\Shared drives\(insert drive name)\STANDARDS\DYNAMO\Packages\2.13\packages" "$env:appdata\..\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.13\packages" /mir
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @DaImTo You say I need to edit my question, but it looks like you edited it? I looked at the link and I think I am succinctly posting the issue and the question along with the 2 lines of code I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ...

```
robocopy "G:\Shared drives\(insert drive name)\STANDARDS\DYNAMO\Packages\2.13\packages" "$env:appdata\..\Roaming\Dynamo\Dynamo Revit\2.13\packages" /mir
```

... is not a valid path.

***$env:appdata evaluates to the following:***

```
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $env:APPDATA).Parent
# Results
<#
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                               
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                               
d-----          9/7/2022   9:18 AM                Roaming                                                                                            
d-----          9/7/2022   9:18 AM                Roaming 
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path $env:APPDATA
# Results
<#
    Directory: C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Roaming


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                               
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                               
d-----          9/7/2022   9:18 AM                Adobe                                                                                              
d---s-         9/21/2022   6:50 PM                Microsoft 
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$env:APPDATA\..\Credentials"
# Results
<#
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\AppData\Credentials' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
#>

Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path "$env:APPDATA\*\Credentials"
# Results
<#

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                                               
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                                               
d---s-          9/7/2022   9:18 AM                Credentials 
#>
```